# Difference of union of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following equality:
$\cup^{n}_{i = 1} A_{i} = \cup^{n}_{i = 1}(A_{i}\backslash (\cup_{k<i} A_{k}))$
I wrote some examples on small $i$'s and I have a very strong intuition why it's true, but I can see how i formally prove it.
I though do it by induction, but I got stuck on the induction step.
I tried sets containment but it didn't lead me to anything.
Would glad for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of standard way to show that two sets are equal is to show that any element from one of them is in the other, and vice versa.

Every following line is equivalent to previous and next:

1. $x \in \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$
2. $\exists i: (x \in A_i \wedge \forall k < i: x \notin A_k)$
3. $\exists i: x \in A_i \wedge x \notin \cup_{k < i} A_k$
4. $\exists i: x \in A_i \setminus \cup_{k < i} A_k$
5. $x \in \cup_{i = 1}^n (A_i \setminus \cup_{k < i} A_k))$

To go from 1 to 2 you need some form of induction: set of $i$ s.t. $x \in A_i$ is not empty, thus it contains minimal element, and we can take this element as our $i$.

Comment: Thank you very much